# changing colors of box in boxplot in r using finalfit / hr_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the package "**finalfit**" to draw boxplot for showing hazard ratio.
However, the colors of the box is making it difficult to read the boxplot as my CI ends are near 1. Here is how it looks like. I am focusing on the 5th and 7th row. The size of the box makes it unclear that the upper CI is < 1.

1. Is there a away to change the color of the box to make it clear ?
2. Is there more elegant way to show this?

[image: sample_boxplot]

Couldn't share my exact data but I replicated the code exactly as this [example](https://finalfit.org/reference/hr_plot.html).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't know the package but if it's ggplot based I would guess there's an anesthetic like color, fill, or even alpha just to make it more transparent...?

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I added neutral transparent colors based on Ewen's code and it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard coded. Slight hack, but you can do this.

```
# HR plot
library(finalfit)
explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = "Surv(time, status)"
colon_s %>%
  hr_plot(dependent, explanatory, 
    plot_opts=list(geom_point(aes(size = Total), shape=22, fill="white"),
                   geom_errorbarh(height=0.2)
    )
  )
```

[image]